# Instrument finds leaks on Simulator, but not on the Device

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, ios-simulator

I was tuning my iPhone app before submission to AppStore, when I noticed that Instrument finds a lot of memory leaks if I run in simulator|debug... but if I run it on the Device Instrument doesn't find any one.... To be honest, there were two leaks and I've fixed them. Now no leaks on the Device, but still too leaks on the Simulator.

Who's right??

Comment: The leaks that are found on Simulator, Are they valid?? Have you already corrected?

Comment: They are not valid. For example, I create some custom buttons by code, with custom labels. Instrument find leaks on both UIButton and UILabel, but there are no leaks: I just alloc\init, add to Subview, and release them!

I also tried to create a leak, and instrument finds it correctly running on the Device (this would mean that instrument is correctly working).

OMG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trust in the device.

The simulator will be using a slightly different memory model - always test on the device :)

Sam

Comment: Thank you. You said me what I wanted someone would say to me :D Ahah, I will trust device, simulator has gone crazy! Stop debugging, let's submit :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have NSZombieEnabled set for your simulator build?  That will cause a lot of leaks to be reported.